# Renovate: exclude or regex repositories?

Tags: github, repository, renovate

**Goal: renovate `repositories`, regex include/exclude**

Using [renovate `repositories`](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#repositories), is it possible to regex to include/exclude?

For example, this explicitly two repositories:

```
  repositories: ["ACT/act-qa", "ACT/act-integration-apps"],
```

But this does not work in including all repositories that begin with a specific string:

```
  repositories: ["ACT/act-*"],
```

Appreciate assistance, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at  [autodiscover](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#autodiscover) and [autodiscoverfilter](https://docs.renovatebot.com/self-hosted-configuration/#autodiscoverfilter)? I believe you will be able to achieve what you want with those properties.

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a project level (Bitbucket Server) with the renovate-config repository?